# Maven wrapper in jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm trying to test build a maven based project in jenkins.

https://github.com/tonsV2/Lift-Log-Backend

However I get the following error.

```
[Lift Log Backend] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson4180120395829748105.sh
+ ./mvnw clean
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have spaces in your Jenkins job name. Try to rename your job from "*Lift Log Backend*" to "*Lift-Log-Backend*"

I had the same issue, after renaming the Jenkins job, the error was gone.